# TreeNode Method isEmpty

Tags: java

For WebCat (an automated grader) for my class I have been working with TreeNodes and it checked my work but it highlighted the return line red and said "Not all possibilities for this line were tested" for the following code:

```
public boolean isEmpty()
{       
    return root.val == null && root.rkid == null && root.lkid == null;      
}
```

Does this mean that I must test true and false combinations (eight different tests) for this one line of code?

Is there a simpler return statement? (given a value, a left child, and a right child)

I have been working hard on this assignment for hours and hours, please help!

Comment: It should be `||`, not `&&`, right?

Comment: What happens if `root` is `null`?  Consequentially, why would one care about anything else if the root node is `null`?

Comment: Not sure about tree node.  However, coverage tools check that all branches are followed, which means verifying that every term in the expression is tested to both true and false, AND that testing the two cases leads to different results.

Comment: Try testing root.val == null; then root.val != null with root.rkid == null; then root.val != null with root.rkid != null and root.lkid == null.  And finally with all != null.

Comment: If this weren't for a class I'd ignore it...it's pretty obvious that this line is gonna work as planned.  I would include a case where root is null, however, because that's gonna cause your isEmpty method to fail.